# How to Randomly display the rows in HBase Shell?

Tags: hbase

I am querying HBase to get a set of key and value using the limit clause. Here is the query

```
hbase(main):015:0> scan 'sample_table', {FILTER => "KeyOnlyFilter()",TIMESTAMP => 11, LIMIT => 2}
```

and I get some output. If I repeat the same query I get the same output. What I need is a different output every time I execute the query. In Hive we can use `rand()` to get a different output every time we query with LIMIT clause. I want to know if we have something similar in HBase?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RandomRowFilter`. Constructor parameter `chance` is the probability of a row getting included in the results.

Since `ParseFilter` is used by shell by default and it does not support this filter, we will not be able to use simple filter string like `"RandomRowFilter(0.10) AND PageFilter(10)"`. Instead use something like this:

```
module B
    include_package 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter'
end
filters=B::FilterList.new
filters.addFilter(B::RandomRowFilter.new(0.10))
filters.addFilter(B::PageFilter.new(10))
scan "some_table",{FILTER=>filters}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below if you have idea about the row keys prefix:

```
scan 'table1', {ROWPREFIXFILTER => 'xyz'}
```

Also if you are aware of both start and endkeys,

```
scan 'table2', {STARTROW => 'abc', ENDROW => 'xyz'}
```